# Requires help writing an xpath for last option in a drop down list

Tags: xpath

I am fairly new to coding and I need to help in creating xpath.

I have a dynamic drop down list and need to select a value "Create Client Name" which is a static value.

I got till `//ul[@class='results_list']`. How do I add "create new user" to my xpath expression?

Thanks for your help in advance!!

```
<app-combo-box _ngcontent-c2="" placeholder="Client Name" _nghost-c4="" style="">
    <input _ngcontent-c4="" type="text" placeholder="Client Name" maxlength="100" tabindex="2">
        <ul _ngcontent-c4="" class="results_list" style="right: 43px; width: 382px; top: 32px;">
            <!---->
            <li _ngcontent-c4="" class="selected">
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <h4 _ngcontent-c2="">DAVID MIZRAHI LIVING TRUST</h4>
                <!---->
                <span _ngcontent-c2="">Tax ID: 55-4043677</span>
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-c4="" class="">
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!----> Create Client Name <!---->
                <!---->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </app-combo-box>
```

Comment: I don't see "create new user" in your sample xml, did you mean "Create Client Name"? Are you looking to find the item with that content, like your question body, or the last item in the list as in your title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the XPATH from the html text box  and the XPATH of the list item (copy from the inspect element look-up)

add the XPATH in your script and the value in the text box , since it is not a dynamic value you can hard code and then wait to load the options. Next one is the action 'click' and give the  .

the sample code snippet.

```
input text  <XPATH-OF-THE-TEXTBOX>    "Value"
wait until element is visible  <XPATH> 
click element   <XPATH-OF-THE-LIST-ELEMENT>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select `<li>` that contains specific text inside, then you can use function [`contains(string, string)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains). For example:

```
//ul[@class='results_list']/li[contains(.,'Create Client Name')]
```

From given html it will return:

```
<li _ngcontent-c4="" class="">
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!----> Create Client Name <!---->
    <!---->
</li>
```

If you want to select the last `<li>`, then use function [`last()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-last). The following xpath will return the same result as above(for given html):

```
//ul[@class='results_list']/li[last()]
```